# Asynchronous function call conflicts with deinitialization of an unowned object

Tags: swift, concurrency, automatic-ref-counting, deinit

I have code similar to this, related to event handling in an asynchronous context:

```
class A {
    var foos: Set<Fooable>
}

protocol Fooable {
    func bar()
}

class B {
    var a: A
    var foo: Foo!

    init(a: A) {
        self.a = a
    }

    func start() {
        self.foo = Foo(self)
        self.a.foos.insert(self.foo)
    }

    deinit {
        <... *>
        if self.foo != nil {
            self.a.remove(self.foo)
        }
    }


    class Foo: Fooable {
        unowned let b: B

        init(_ b: B) {
            self.b = B
        }

        func bar() { <... #> }
    }
}
```

I figured that this should be safe code: before an instance of `b` is gone, it cleans up all references to its `foo`, so the reference `Foo.b` should never be an issue.

However, I get this error from an access of `self.b` inside of `Foo.bar()` (run on some GCD queue, not main):

> exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt subcode=0x0)

The debugger shows that `self.b` is completely fine: not nil, all values are as they should be.

However, the debugger also shows that, at the same time, the main thread is busy *deinitializing* the corresponding `B`; it's paused in `<... *>`, i.e. before the reference to `foo` could be removed from `a`. So it makes sense to me that `self.b` would be a bad reference at this point in time.

This seems to be unfortunate timing -- but how can I do away with this crash potential? I can not prevent asynchronous calls to `bar()` from happening, after all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, we are breaking the precondition of `unowned` here: even though the debugger doesn't show it, `Foo.b` *can* become `nil` during the lifetime of a `Foo`. The compiler believed us when we claimed (by use of `unowned`) that it couldn't, so we crash.

There seem to be two ways out.

1. Make sure that `Foo.b` is the last object that holds a strong reference to the respective instance of `Foo`. Then, the two objects should be removed "together", resp. there is no way a call to `Foo.bar()` can happen while `Foo.b` is being deinitialized (or after that).
2. Make `Foo.b` a weak reference, i.e. declare it as `weak var b: B?`. That makes the code more messy, but at least it can be made safe.